# how get an RGB color in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

i need to define a *static color* to access that for use in whole my project.
i'd  like use that same below syntax

```
let my color = staticColor
```

what's a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your answer is

```
extension UIColor {

static func rgb(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)->UIColor{
return UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: alpha)

}

static func colorA() -> UIColor {
return UIColor(red: 146/255, green: 39/255, blue: 143/255, alpha: 1)
}


static func colorB() -> UIColor {
return UIColor(red: 173/255, green: 104/255, blue: 173/255, alpha: 1)
}
}
```

Comment: It would be better to declare the custom colors as class properties instead of functions, just like UIColor does.